# Add user-level function to MPICH3.3.*

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, mpi, mpich

I need to add a user-level function, `MPI_Myfunc()`, to **MPICH-3.3.2**. I add the function prototype to **src/include/mpi.h.in** where other prototypes are (MPI_Send, ...), and I implement it in the **src/mpi/coll/allgather/allgather.c**. I can compile and build MPICH without any issues. However, when I want to compile a test program that calls `MPI_Myfunc()`, I get this error:

> undefined reference to `MPI_Myfunc`.

I don't get this error when I follow the same procedure in `MPICH-3.2.1`. I wonder if there is a change in the `MPICH-3.3.2` that I'm not aware of.

How should I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding the following to the function prototype at **/src/invlude/mpi.h.in**:

```
MPICH_ATTR_POINTER_WITH_TYPE_TAG(1,3) MPICH_API_PUBLIC;
```

So, the function prototype looks like this:

```
void MPI_Myfunc() MPICH_ATTR_POINTER_WITH_TYPE_TAG(1,3) MPICH_API_PUBLIC;
```